# jQuery check for inline Styling

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying to write a short script which checks for inline styling that's added to one of my divs from a jQuery plugin I'm running, then add a css style to another div.

The inline styling I'm looking for is `position: fixed`

My code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if( $('.nav-container').attr('position:fixed;') {
        $('.recent-episodes').css('padding-top', '90px');
    } else {
        $('.recent-episodes').css('padding-top', '0px');
    }
});
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

`position:fixed` is a style, not an attribute. Change

```
if( $('.nav-container').attr('position:fixed;') {
```

to

```
if( $('.nav-container').css('position')=='fixed') {
```

Comment: It should. Perhaps the problem is elsewhere in your code. Without a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) I can't identify the problem any better than this.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you,

```
if( $('.nav-container').css('position')==='fixed') {
    $('.recent-episodes').css('padding-top', '90px');
}
else {
    $('.recent-episodes').css('padding-top', '0px');
}
```